# How can I select a nested child element of a parent element that has a dynamic ID?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, tampermonkey

I'm currently toying around with Zendesk, and trying to make changes to a text element on the page.  Sadly, Zendesk's elements are dynamic enough that the name of the main element will change on each page load.

Thankfully the structure of the element trees stay pretty static, but it's only the parent element's name that's changing:

```
#ember6030 > div.comment > div > p
```

```
#ember3483 > div.comment > div > p
```

Currently, here's where I'm at so far:

```
var item = document.querySelectorAll("[name^=ember] > div.comment > div > p");
var itemtext = item.innerHTML;
console.log(itemtext);
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but wouldn't my selector var be correct?

Something like finding an element that begins with "ember"  but then follows the rest of the parent-child tree just fine.

---

EDIT: Things are being a bit more stubborn than I thought, but I've got some extra details if this helps: For the `div.comment > div > p` elements, a handful of those load up.  For right now, I'd like to try targeting just one, but if I can get the text contents of all these elements in console messages, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those CSS paths you would use:

```
var item = document.querySelector("[id^=ember] > div.comment > div > p");
var itemtext = item.textContent;
console.log(itemtext);
```

since `#` is the CSS selector for the `id` attribute, not the `name`.

See also [David Klinge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55860730/331508) about NodeLists.

So the **final code is:**

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=ember] > div.comment > div > p");
items.forEach (item => {
  var itemtext = item.textContent;
  console.log(itemtext);
} );
```

---

Finally, for what you seem to be trying to do, you probably want `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.  This avoids false hits on attributes, comments, etc.

Comment: Great point about `textContent`.  Sadly, no luck just yet with your version.  Running the script gives me "undefined", so I'm wondering if maybe I'm getting this part wrong too.  This page certainly does have a LOT of other elements structured exactly like this, so I tried switching things up by using only `QuerySelector` instead of `QuerySelectorAll` , thinking I could grab the text contents of whatever element the script found first, but sadly no-go there either.  I also tried narrowing things down even further by going for `[id^=ember] > div.comment > div > p:nth-child(1)` .

Comment: Thanks so much for being so patient while working with me on this, Brock.  The good news now is that I'm not picking up any undefined errors or any errors for that matter, but so far no luck with seeing the console post a message with the text contents.  I'm not sure if this helps give us a different plan of attack, but the class name of `div.comment > div` comes up as `zd-comment`.  Would it be easier to target that with `GetElementsbyClassName` , or is that essentially just the opposite side of the same coin here?

Comment: @RufioBangarang, you need to edit the question to contain a link to the target page. Or, if that's not feasible, edit in a [mcve].  (And then comment reply if you want us to see the change.)

Comment: I want to thank you again for all the help, as well as David's help too.  Of course, the examples from you and David were correct, and it turns out that the main issue was simply a matter of timing.  Once I set up the script in a setInterval of at least 2 seconds before firing, your example code successfully pulled up all the text contents from every element matching that parent/child structure.  Bless! Even for other elements, the script is carrying over beautifully.  

Marking this question as answered.  Thanks again guys!

Comment: @RufioBangarang, You're welcome.  For the timing problem, a more robust approach is to use `MutationObserver` or `waitForKeyElements`.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` that must be iterated over.  You should be able to use a `forEach` to iterate over the elements `querySelectorAll` selects.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=ember] > div.comment > div > p");
items.forEach (item => {
  var itemtext = item.textContent;
  console.log(itemtext);
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! Great point about the `NodeList` portion there.  Sadly, Tampermonkey picked up an "Unexpected token {" right after `(item)`, so I tried switching things up to look like this.  Am I getting colder?
`var items = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=ember] > div.comment > div > p");
items.forEach (item) {
  var itemtext = item.textContent;
  console.log(itemtext); }`

Comment: @RufioBangarang, he had a syntax error.  Now corrected in both answers.